# Como passo um array de objetos por props?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import Usuarios from './component/Usuarios'

let usuarios :{
  name: string;
  id: string;
}[];

usuarios = [
  {name:"Usuario 01", id:"01"},
  {name:"Usuario 02", id:"02"}
]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Usuarios users={usuarios} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

****

import React from 'react';
const Usuarios: React.FC<{users: object[]}> = (props) => {
 
    return(
        <ul>
           {props.users.map((us) => (
            <li>{props.users.map((us) => (
                {us.?????} Não consigo pegar o atributo **name** e **id**
            ))}</li>
           ))}
        </ul>
    )
}

export default Usuarios;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá!

Ao colocar a tipagem de uma props no seu componente React chamado Usuarios, você passou um tipo genérico chamado "object", se você quer usar o intellisense dentro do componente como props, você deve **forçar** o tipo correto do objeto desejado que é contido dentro da lista.

Como assim?

No seu caso, você criou um array de objetos que possuem name e id, mas não têm um tipo definido, apenas suas **propriedades** têm tipos definidos, mas não o **objeto em si**.

Ok, e qual a solução então?

Existem diversas maneiras, porém uma forma fácil seria você criar um tipo customizado para cada usuário, e na hora de colocar as props do seu componente, passar o tipo dela como um Array de objetos do seu tipo customizado.

Exemplos:

```js
type TipoCustomizado = {
  propriedade: tipo;
}

type ArrayDeTiposCustomizados = TipoCustomizado[];

export type MeuTipoCustomizado = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const MeuComponente: React.FC<{ items: MeuTipoCustomizado[]; items2: ArrayDeTiposCustomizados }> = ({ items, items2 }) => {
  console.log("Array com tipos 1 ", items);
  console.log("Array com tipos 2", items2);

  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

Coloquei dois exemplos diferentes pra chegar no mesmo resultado, basta você escolher qual te agrada mais.

Espero que tenha ficado claro! Boa noite!

Comment: Olá amigo, agradeço muito pela ajuda